# How to adjust space in-between <a> and <p>

Tags: css, text, space

I'm trying to understand the best way to adjust the space in-between `<a>` elements and `<p>` elements.

Here is a CodePen I have made for this: http://codepen.io/theclarkofben/pen/jEVWgz

I am looking specifically only to adjust the space between the red and blue text. I do not want to adjust the space after the blue paragraph text or before the red hyperlink text.

So far I have played with `line-height` - however that adjusted space after the blue so wasn't appropriate.

I have also played with `-webkit-margin-before` `-webkit-margin-after` but crucially i'm looking for something cross browser compatible.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: Why don't you just use `margin`?

Comment: Just give a top margin to the paragraph. Note that top/bottom `margin` is applicable to block containers.

Comment: For some reason, probably a mistake of some kind, when I tried margin previously it wasn't having the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `margin-top: 0;`, `margin-bottom:0;` and `padding-top:0;` `padding-bottom:0;` to selectors `a,p`

*You can adjust the space by adjusting these values.*

```css
a {
  color:red;
  text-decoration:none;
}
p {
  color:blue;
  
}
a, p{
  padding-top:0;   /* Here is the code I added */
  padding-bottom:0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<h3>Blog Articles</h3>
        <a href="http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/6126/The-Ultimate-Glossary-120-Social-Media-Marketing-Terms-Explained.aspx">The Ultimate Social Media Glossary</a>
        <p>Found this and had to share</p>
        <h4>Influencer Outreach And Management - 5 Easy Tips</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>Looking for influencers shouldn’t be hard - find the ones that like you already</li>
            <li>Communicate openly, honestly, and frequently with your influencers</li>
            <li>Know their worth and treat them with respect</li>
            <li>Give some creative freedom - people believe people, not advertising</li>
            <li>Finally and very important - don’t leave them hanging. If you run a campaign with influencers, make sure you keep in touch afterwards and nurture the relationship.</li>
        </ul>
```